# Instantiate an Object from an IType

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I would like to know if Eclipse JDT is offering any API functions to instantiate an object from an `IType`.

We are using the Eclipse JDT search engine to retrieve classes with a particular interface, say `Application` that looks like this:

```
public interface Application {
    void launch();
}
```

Using the JDT search engine, we are able to get an `IType` object that represents a class that implements the `Application` interface. Assume that the implementing class has a no-argument constructor.

What we try to achieve is to get a concrete `Object` from the `IType`. So, I would like to know if the JDT offers any API functions to do so.

If it does, we will use it to instantiate the `IType`. If it doesn't, we will locate the containing projects, build a `ClassLoader` from it and then use reflection to instantiate the class directly.

Thansk in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Reflection is the way to go.

Comment: I think Matt is saying, he needs the ClassLoader of the project so he can create the instance from the class in the right project.

Comment: The right classloader would depend on the kind of application - plain Java, OSGI, or something else.

Comment: Still, no, JDT doesn't provide an API specifically to do that (instantiating an object from an IType).

Comment: @mP No and yes, in the end I want an instance. I wanted to know if JDT offers something like this for an IType, like `ITypes.newInstance(IJavaProject project)`. If it is not offered, I will compute the ClassLoader myself by exploring project and dependencies to load a class and instantiate an actual object. We have already something like this in our codebase.
@nitind and @Deepak Excatly what I wanted to know. We gonna go via reflection then. I'll juts wait a bit before accepting your answer, just to check if other answers come up.

Comment: Thank you for your time, since it seems there is no other solutions, I accepted your answer.